# Optimized way for Finding prime numbers upto given value n

Tags: c, algorithm

I am doing it by checking it from `k=3` to `n` (given upper value) using this function for each value `k`. How can I optimize it to take all prime numbers till `n` in an array and not need to check for each number `k`?

```
int primeCheck(long long int k) {
    int j;
    int isPrime = 1;
    int sr = (int)sqrt(k);
    for (j = 2; j <= sr; j++) {
        if (k % j == 0) {
            //printf("=========== %d|%d\n", num,num2); // uncomment this to see if a number is divisible
            isPrime = 0; // this number is not prime, cos num can be divided by num2
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
        return isPrime; // reset the check parameter
    } else {
        return 0; // reset the check parameter
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, one quick optimization is not to check all the even numbers.  (There are plenty more.  probably start with googling sieve of Eratosthenes)

Comment: Start with a primes array that contains just [2], and a counter set to 1. Then, check every odd number starting with 3, use the array of primes found so far to check if the new number is a prime, and every time you find a new prime, append it to the array of primes, and increment the count of how many you have found so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Sieve of Eratosthenes. This algorithm works by eliminating all the factors of a prime number from `2` to `n`.

```
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int prime[n+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
        prime[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n+1); i++) {
        if(prime[i] == 0) {
            for(int j = i*i; j <= n; j += i)
                prime[j] = 1;
        }
    }

    int prime_list[n], size = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if(prime[i] == 0)
            prime_list[size++] = i;
    }
}
```

For example let the number initially be:

`2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30`

- Removing all multiples of `2`(except `2`) we get:

`2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29`

- Removing all multiples of `3` (except `3`), we get:

`2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29`

- Removing all multiples of `5` (except `5`), we get:

`2 3 7 11 13 17 19 23 29`

Now, there will be no more removals and after a few more iterations for each of the remaining prime numbers, this will be our final list.

The `prime[i]` for `i = {2, 3, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29}`. We will append all these indices to another `prime_list` vector as done in the code. This vector will give all the prime numbers from `[2, n]`.

Comment: `prime` does not need such a large type, `unsigned char` would suffice.  The name itself is confusing.  It would be less risky to allocate it with `calloc()` instead of via a VLA, which will invoke undefined behavior for any sufficiently large value of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also skip even numbers after 2. something like

```
int primeCheck(long long int k){
    if(k<=1 || k%2==0){    //if number is even return 0 its not prime
        return 0;
    }

    int sr = (int) sqrt(k);    //probable divisor

    for(int j=3;j<=sr;j+=2){
        if(k%j == 0){
            //printf("=========== %d|%d\n", num,num2); // uncomment this to see if a number is divisable
            return 0; //if number is not prime skip everything and return zero
        }
    }
    return 1; //if loop completes i.e. not divisor found then return return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to check a lot of numbers in a range I recommend Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm.**

your function could be better a bit:

```
int primeCheck(long long int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n <= 3)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int sr = (int)sqrt(n);

        for (int i = 5; i <= sr; i += 6)
        {
            if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```